# django query to get data

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am into a very confusing situation where I have one to many relation and I want to query data like I want all parent table data  but want to get only data from child tables which fulfill condition of site_id = 100.

```
class Policy(Base):
    """table containing details for Policies"""
    __tablename__ = "UmbrellaPolicy"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    policy_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    user_defined_name = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
```

and child is like this

```
class Site(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Site"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    policy_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Policy.id"))
    site_id = Column(String(32), nullable=False, index=True)
    policy = relationship("Policy", backref="sites")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to filter join relations like this

```py
parents = Policy.objects.filter(site__site_id=100)
```

You can find more info about the Django query API [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/) but its generally of the form where you reference the relation with `classname__columnname` there are many other ways to filter/query that you can reference in the docs